# How to center an element where the width is not 100%

Tags: html, css, text, web, center

I created a `title` and I made the `width: 30%` so that I could create a box around it, but now it isn't centered. I have tried many different things to get it centered, but none have worked. I am able to center it myself by adding `left: 35%`. But that isn't perfectly centered. Any ideas on how I can perfectly center my `title`, while the `width` is not at `100%`?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Add the html code, (maybe CSS aswell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use left and right margin's set to auto to achieve this.

`margin: 0 auto;`

```css
h1{
 width: 30%;
 border: 2px solid black;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  margin : 0;  /* for cross browsers */
  padding : 0; /* for cross browsers */
 }
div{
  text-align : center; /* text alignment */
  width : 30%;
  margin : auto;       /* block alignment center */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Title</label>
</div>
```